Computed array not recalculating
DISCLAIMER ON DUPLICATE QUESTION
There are lots of SO questions with this same premise, however, many are old and the question/answer is based on vue2.  Given how different vue2 and vue3 are, a new question seems appropriate.
QUESTION
I have two computed properties like so:
 const transactions_map = computed(()=>{
    if (!tenants.value){
      return {}
    }
    const _val = {};
    for (const [key, value] of tenants.value.entries()){
      const _transactions = value.transactions;
      const nm = DataMap.fromArray(_transactions, {sortKey: 'date'})
      _val[key] = nm;
    }
    return _val
  })

  const transactions_with_balance = computed(() => {
    const return_value = {}
    Object.entries(transactions_map.value)
      .forEach(([key, value])=>{
        let prevTotal = 0;
        const nm = new DataMap()
        for (const [tran_key, tran_val] of value.entries()){
          const _tran = {...tran_val};
          _tran.balance = _tran.amount + prevTotal
          prevTotal = _tran.balance
          nm.set(tran_key, _tran)
      }
      return_value[key] = nm
    })
    return return_value
  })

If I add a value to the array returned by transactions_map, it is not reflected in transactions_with_balance.
transactions_map['some_tenant_id'].set('some_transaction_id', new_transaction_object)

According to the vue3 docs it should be deeply reactive
The DataMap object in this example is just a Map class that contains some helpers.  Could it be Vue3 cant detect changes to an underlying map?
Reproduction here

transactions_map is a computed value, you should not be altering it manually. If you rewrite it into a ref it should work. Even in the link you provided yourself the example of 'deeply reactive' uses ref not computed helper function.
Computed is just a way for vue to cache a result of a function instead of calling it on every rerender within the template.

Vue documentation states to avoid mutating computed properties to not experience unusual behaviour https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#avoid-mutating-computed-value

I guess you need to add the data directly to the ref tenants. Or create a watcher and generate the the map as a ref instead of computed.

Computed properties are intended to self-update when they see their dependencies changing, in this case tenants. Calling .set on a computed property is not the intended way to modify one.
The docs tell us how to define a setter method for when we are overriding the content, or to modify one or more of the upstream values that it is reactively observing.
I believe you are bypassing the reactivity by modifying the proxy object rather than letting it react to a data change.
Pinia doesn't really come into it as shown, but a Pinia object in place of your computed property with a modify action could do what you need but then you're acquiring another singleton... The getters would at least always reflect the current state.
